# Python declaring a list of variables without initializing them

Tags: python, list, variables

I need to declare an array of variables to be used later, but without initializing any of the variables inside, is it possible?.
I need this to make a function use easier as i have to perform some mathematical operations on the vector varlist, which is the input of another function.
Can anybody help?

```
varlist=[]
for i in range(0,10):
 varlistchar="varlist"+str(i+1)
 vl=globals()[varlistchar] #=0.
 varlist.append(vl)
```

the commented part makes the code functional but doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: Fill the `varlist` with any type, then just reassign values via indexing.

Comment: Please, consider marking an answer as accepted if you consider one as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's better to use the index of the list as variable : `variable[index]`

Or if you want to use named variables... use a **Dictionary{key : value}** instead of list.

Answer (score 0):

remove `globals()` from the code. `globals()` is used for calling a global variable inside a function.

```py
varlist=[]
for i in range(0,10):
    varlistchar="varlist"+str(i+1)
    vl = varlistchar
    varlist.append(vl)

print(varlist)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['varlist1', 'varlist2', 'varlist3', 'varlist4', 'varlist5', 'varlist6', 'varlist7', 'varlist8', 'varlist9', 'varlist10']
```